How to move all pictures in my iphone to an album
Over the time, a bit over 1000 pictures have been accumulated, and I would move ALL of them at once into a new album (no detailed organization on the topic of the pictures wanted).
I have created a new album, named it J24. I can inside the album type "add" (actually, it is "Hinzufügen", since I'm using the German interface), and then I could select the photos to be put into the album. However, I want to select all of them, and individually selecting, or even swiping, is too cumbersome with this number of photos.
How can I achieve it in a simpler way?


Switch to library view
Tap Select at the top
Select all the photos by dragging your finger over them. It autoscrolls, selecting 1000 pictures takes about 15 seconds on my phone
Tap on the sharing icon at bottom left and select „Add to Album“


"dragging your finger over them" is, AFIK, called "swiping". Did you ever try it with 1000+ photos? That's why I said that I am searching a different solution than swiping.

@user1934428 did you try? It takes about 15 seconds to select 1000 photos.

Also, you don‘t swipe. You just mark them by dragging your finger over them.

Ah, got it now, after starting all over. Seems that I have not been in "library view". But what happened now, was that the pictures were copied to the new album. They still are visible in the "main" album, where I marked them. So it was not moving, but copying.

@user1934428 The main album is your library, you can‘t move photos out of it. They are not copied to albums though, albums just group photos in the library.

Are the library entries which I copied just symbolic links? So when I delete a picture in what I called "main album", it would also disappear from the library?

@user1934428 yes, photos deleted from the library will be gone everywhere.

I see. I think I need to answer a new question then. Thank you for your help.

@user1934428 IIRC that other question is already on AD somewhere.

I just asked it here. If you would have a time, would you kindly have a look? I think that what I want to achieve is pretty exotic, and maybe there is so solution for it.
